# How can I nest setInterval and setTimeout in my function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

Good Morning,

I have a javascript function which, in turn, calls several functions.
I would like to trigger the function (check1 in my example below) half a second after the javascript function is called and subsequently call the same function check1 every 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds). Having done some researches, I found out - I might be wrong though - that the combination of setInterval and setTimeout would have made the deal.

Unfortunately, the outcome was not as expected.

Afterwards, I made a second trial by using the clearInterval() but I was not sure either how to nest these various functions.

Is there an elegant and smart way to achieve this ? Many thanks in advance for your help

Here below is my javascript code:

```
// Global variables
var AutoScript = false;
var IntervalRefresh1 = 500;
var newIntervalDefined1 = false;

// calls the startUp method
startUp();


function startUp()
{
  console.log("I'm the startup2");
  setInterval(check1, IntervalRefresh1);
}


function check1()
{
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'php/checker1.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
  counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
  }
  }).done(function( response ) {
  /* check if with response we got a new update */
  if(response.update==true)
  {
    var j = response.news;      
    $('#message-list').html(response.news);
    AutoScript = true;
    // here I call a specific method named after getDataFromDatabase(j);
    AutoScript = false;        
    if (newIntervalDefined1 == false)
    {
      setTimeout(check1, 10000);
      newIntervalDefined1 == true;
    }
  }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `check1` in an interval but not clearing it. So this will keep getting called every `500` miliseconds.

`setInterval(check1, IntervalRefresh1);`

On the top, you're calling the function again with `setTimeout`. You must clear that too at some point based on a condition so that it doesn't run infinitely. See the code and comments.

```
var timerinterval;
var timeout;
function startUp()
{
  console.log("I'm the startup2");
  timerinterval = window.setInterval(check1, IntervalRefresh1); //set a timerInterval
}


function check1()
{
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'php/checker1.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
  counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
  }
  }).done(function( response ) {
  /* check if with response we got a new update */
  if(response.update==true)
  {
    var j = response.news;      
    $('#message-list').html(response.news);
    AutoScript = true;
    // here I call a specific method named after getDataFromDatabase(j);
    AutoScript = false;        
    if (newIntervalDefined1 == false)
    {
      clearInterval(timerinterval); //clear the interval timer
     timeout =  setTimeout(check1, 10000); //now clear this too at some point of time so that it doesn run infinitely
      newIntervalDefined1 == true;
    }
  }
  });
```

Comment: thank you very much, ABGR. What I don't understand is why I should clear the timout as well if I want check1 to run every 10 seconds ad infinitum ? Or maybe I'm missing a point.

Comment: If you want to run it infinitely, you don't have to clear it. But normally you want to stop it at some time. However, If you deliberately want to allow it, you may do so.

Answer (score 0):

Never use setInterval with async/ajax

Just use the setTimeout

OR move

setTimeout(check1, 10000);

to your special function

```js
// Global variables
var AutoScript = false;

function check1() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/checker1.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      counter: $('#message-list').data('counter')
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
    /* check if with response we got a new update */
    if (response.update == true) {
      var j = response.news;
      $('#message-list').html(response.news);
      AutoScript = true;
      // here I call a specific method named after getDataFromDatabase(j);
      AutoScript = false;
      setTimeout(check1, 10000);
    }
  });
}
$(function() {
  check1()
})
```